# Error in Compiler,js Error comes as : Can't resolve all parameters for setupPlatform: (?, [object Object], [object Object]) error on ionic serve

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-upgrade

I have updated from Angular 7 to Angular 8, and after updating when I am trying to run ionic serve, it gives me an error for SetupPlatfrom.

I tried searching for DOCUMENT import we have not used that import, check for @injectable as well in the providers.. so in the created providers the @injectable annotation is there other Providers are ionic libraries like qrscanner, device etc, anyother help will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.